# Letsrate gem - doesn't show stars

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use [letsrate](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate) gem and follow the instructions on github. I already have models `user.rb` and `hotel.rb`. Also I use command `rails g letsrate user` and add functions `letsrate_rater`, `letsrate_rateable` to models.

**Model user.rb :**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  letsrate_rater
end
```

**Model hotel.rb :**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  letsrate_rateable "rating"
end
```

The problem is, when i try to output current variable with rating it doesn't show any stars.

**View show.html.erb :**

```
...
<div>Rating: <%= rating_for @hotel, "rating" %></div>
```

@hotel variable isn't empty, i'm getting above @hotel.title and it's working. When I'm doing "expect element"  it shows me:

```
'Rating: ' 
<div class="star" data-classname="Hotel" data-dimension="rating"
     data-id="4" data-rating="0" data-star-count="5"></div>
```

So helper is working, but there are now stars. Maybe something with pipeline? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should include javascript files. Add in view (in my case `show.html.erb`):

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.raty.js','letsrate.js'%>
<% end %>
```

And after add in `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= yield :javascript_includes %>
```